# Determine installed PowerShell version

Tags: powershell, version

How can I determine what version of PowerShell is installed on a computer, and indeed if it is installed at all?

Comment: `pwsh --version` should work fine. I checked on windows 11.

Comment: @Kapil please post that as an answer so it can be voted on along with the rest of the answers. Anyway, it didn't work for me on Windows 10.

Comment: @Kapil `pwsh` only works as a command if a newer PowerShell version is installed. For older versions, such as the PowerShell 5 that comes with Windows 10, the executable is called `PowerShell.exe`. (And there's no `--version` either in older versions.)

Comment: @Kapil This may also be misleading when there are different Power Shell versions running, like after installing PS 7 on top of PS 5.

Comment: Can anyone comment why the two proposed methods to determine the installed powershell version deliver a different result?

>pwsh --version 
PowerShell 7.4.0

>$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      22621  2506

Comment: @MerlinC that's because you're running both commands in the old version of powershell. When you run `pwsh` you're launching Powershell 7 from inside Powershell 5.

Answer (score 3810, accepted):

Use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` to determine the engine version. If the variable does not exist, it is safe to assume the engine is version `1.0`.

Note that `$Host.Version` and `(Get-Host).Version` are not reliable - they reflect
the version of the host only, not the engine. PowerGUI,
PowerShellPLUS, etc. are all hosting applications, and
they will set the host's version to reflect their product
version — which is entirely correct, but not what you're looking for.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on $Host.Version, the registry is better.  I'm on XP and have only PS1 installed, as shown in the registry and file system, and when I do $Host.Version I get this:   
Major  Minor  Build  Revision  
-----  -----  -----  --------  
2      0      -1     -1

Comment: @DanielCassidy - two years late to the party, but "some features are unaccountably unavailable" might be caused by only having the .Net 3.5 Compact framework installed instead of the full thing.

Comment: `$PSVersionTable` is more reliable and returns $PSVersion. You can also use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`. Even if you are connected remotely to the machine running different version (`invoke-command -computername myRemotePC -Credential foo {$host}`), it looks like `$host` will just show the lowest version they agreed upon for serializing. While `$PSVersionTable` will show the true version. Hope it would help someone..

Comment: Seems $host.Version isn't a good choice... If you remote to a machine running PowerShell 3, you get back 1.0, as the RemotingHost seems to be v1. Using $PSVersionTable correctly returns 3.

Comment: $PSVersionTable is better: If you're using the PowerShell Inside PowerShell Server (SSH to PowerShell), it reports its own version (5.x) in $host, but $PSVersionTable reports that it's running version 2.0 of PowerShell, which is important for determining what features are available.

Comment: I know it's late in the day, but `$host.version` is just plain wrong/unreliable. This gives you the version of the hosting executable (powershell.exe, powergui.exe, powershell_ise.exe, powershellplus.exe etc) and not the version of the engine itself. The engine version is `$psversiontable.psversion` For powershell 1.0, this variable does not exist so you can assume 1.0, obviously :)

Comment: @Starfish The command shown launches Powershell using Command Prompt. Wouldn't the command just error out with "powershell not found" if it's not installed?

Comment: Keep in mind the old SQLPS "minishell" had a `$PSVersionTable`, but was *between* versions 1 and 2. See [The Truth about SQLPS and PowerShell V2](http://sev17.com/2010/05/27/the-truth-about-sqlps-and-powershell-v2/ "The Truth about SQLPS and PowerShell V2")

Comment: PowerShell may be installed, but not be included in `%PATH%`. So your command is useless in cases like that. A more sure way to determine if it indeed is *installed* would be to look for a registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell`

Comment: So tired of coming back here for this that I just ran `notepad $profile` and dumped `function psver { $PSVersionTable; $PSVersionTable.PSVersion }` in it. A reload with `. $profile` and I can just type `psver` any time to get the detailed version info and other details.

Answer (score 457):

I would use either **[Get-Host](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849946.aspx)** or **$PSVersionTable**.  As Andy Schneider points out, `$PSVersionTable` doesn't work in version 1; it was introduced in version 2.

```
get-host

Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : d730016e-2875-4b57-9cd6-d32c8b71e18a
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-GB
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4200
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: thank you! NB: On my XP where I manually upgraded from v1 Powershell, the actual folder and registry paths (misleadingly?!) reference v1 NOT v2. This is as others here specify, but it was the reason why I was so worried whether I had installed it. My path is ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0

Comment: If $psversiontable does not exist, it's entirely safe to assume you're on v1.0 - and hey presto, that also answers your question. `$host.version` is not reliable - for example in powergui, it returns the powergui host version which is not the same as the powershell engine version (which is what is desired.)

Comment: The accepted answer states *"... $Host.Version and (Get-Host).Version are not reliable - they reflect the version of the host only, not the engine"*.

Answer (score 106):

You can look at the built in variable, `$psversiontable`. If it doesn't exist, you have V1. If it does exist, it will give you all the info you need.

```
1 >  $psversiontable

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4927                                  
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385                                  
PSVersion                      2.0                                             
WSManStackVersion              2.0                                             
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}                                      
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                         
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Answer (score 100):

To determine if PowerShell is installed, you can check the registry for the existence of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\Install
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3
```

and, if it exists, whether the value is 1 (for installed), as detailed in the blog post *[Check if PowerShell installed and version](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2007/08/16/check-if-powershell-installed-and-version.aspx)*.

To determine the version of PowerShell that is installed, you can check the registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine\PowerShellVersion
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine\PowerShellVersion
```

To determine the version of PowerShell that is installed from a .ps1 script, you can use the following one-liner, as detailed on PowerShell.com in *[Which PowerShell Version Am I Running](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/09/11/which-powershell-version-am-i-running.aspx)*.

```
$isV2 = test-path variable:\psversiontable
```

The same site also gives a function to return the version:

```
function Get-PSVersion {
    if (test-path variable:psversiontable) {$psversiontable.psversion} else {[version]"1.0.0.0"}
}
```

Comment: Useful because on a Windows 2003 server I couldn't find the start menu entry for PowerShell (it was there but not obvious), but the registry key answered my question.

Comment: For PowerScript 3.0 there seems to be a new entry, *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3* (in addition to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1*). The proper place in this case for getting the version appears to be *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine\PowerShellVersion* (sample value is "3.0").

Answer (score 60):

You can directly check the version with one line only by invoking PowerShell *externally*, such as from Command Prompt

```
powershell -Command "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion"
```

According to [@psaul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9226723/psaul) you **can** actually have one command that is agnostic from where it came (CMD, PowerShell or Pwsh). Thank you for that.

```
powershell -command "(Get-Variable PSVersionTable -ValueOnly).PSVersion"
```

I've tested and it worked flawlessly on both CMD and PowerShell.

[image]

Comment: I get this horrible error with that try: "System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion : The term 'System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.". So not always works

Comment: I'm glad that you pointed that out since it's good to know the corner cases, but I guess it still works for the majority of people.

Comment: @Gonmator one would think PowerShell would behave the same way with this command, but it unfortunately does not.  I made attempt to fix the syntax to work agnostically between `cmd` and `powershell` to no avail.  I would have expected the same behavior as well. :)

Comment: @tresf (and @Gonmator) you CAN run this agnostically from CMD, PowerShell, or even Pwsh (PS 6.0) but you need to use this form: powershell -command "(Get-Variable PSVersionTable -ValueOnly).PSVersion"      (that will work in all cases)

Comment: Tested on mac too.  `pwsh -Command "(Get-Variable PSVersionTable -ValueOnly).PSVersion" ` works great.

Answer (score 46):

You can verify that Windows PowerShell version installed by completing the following check:

1. Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, click Windows PowerShell, and then click Windows PowerShell.
2. In the Windows PowerShell console, type the following command at the command prompt and then press ENTER:

   ```
   Get-Host | Select-Object Version
   ```

You will see output that looks like this:

```
Version
-------
3.0
```

http://www.myerrorsandmysolutions.com/how-to-verify-the-windows-powershell-version-installed/

Comment: You assume that powershell was installed with default options and that the shortcuts were not removed from the Start Menu.

Better to use the registry test.

Comment: I think that if you need to use PowerShell first you try to run it as standard it should be installed, then if you don't find the icon your try to search it, then maybe you try to run it from the Command Prompt. I don't think you start from the registry.

Comment: The accepted answer states *"... $Host.Version and (Get-Host).Version are not reliable - they reflect the version of the host only, not the engine"*.

Answer (score 24):

[Microsoft's recommended forward compatible method for checking if PowerShell is installed and determining the installed version](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/06/25/detection-logic-poweshell-installation.aspx?Redirected=true) is to look at two specific registry keys. I've reproduced the details here in case the link breaks.

According to the linked page:

> Depending on any other registry key(s), or version of PowerShell.exe or the location of PowerShell.exe is not guaranteed to work in the long term.

To check if **any version** of PowerShell is installed, check for the following value in the registry:

- Key Location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1`
- Value Name: Install
- Value Type: REG_DWORD
- Value Data: 0x00000001 (1

To check **whether version 1.0 or 2.0** of PowerShell is installed, check for the following value in the registry:

- Key Location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine`
- Value Name: PowerShellVersion
- Value Type: REG_SZ
- Value Data: <1.0 | 2.0>

Comment: For PowerShell 3.0, there appears to be a new one, *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3*.

Comment: The link is dead; it says "403 Forbidden".

Answer (score 11):

I found the easiest way to check if installed was to:

- run a command prompt (Start, Run, `cmd`, then OK)
- type `powershell` then hit return.  You should then get the PowerShell `PS` prompt:

```
C:\Users\MyUser>powershell

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\MyUser>
```

You can then check the version from the PowerShell prompt by typing `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUser> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

PS C:\Users\MyUser>
```

Type `exit` if you want to go back to the command prompt (`exit` again if you want to also close the command prompt).

To run scripts, see http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-run.html.

Comment: Like for [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version/1825807#1825807)  this doesn't return anything for PowerShell 1.0. [The registry method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version/1825604#1825604) is more explicit.

Comment: If powershell was not in the path, this version will give a false impression that it is not installed.  The Registry method gives full information.  Presence and version.

Answer (score 11):

## PowerShell 7

The accepted answer is only appropriate if one version of PowerShell is installed on a computer. With the advent of PowerShell 7, this scenario becomes increasingly unlikely.

Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows#registry-keys-created-during-installation) states that additional registry keys are created when PowerShell 7 is installed:

> Beginning in PowerShell 7.1, the [installer] package creates registry keys
> that store the installation location and version of PowerShell. These
> values are located in
> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\InstalledVersions\<GUID>`. The
> value of `<GUID>` is unique for each build type (release or preview),
> major version, and architecture.

Exploring the registry in the aforementioned location reveals the following registry value: `SemanticVersion`. This value contains the information we seek.

On my computer it appears like the following:

```
Path                                                                                           Name              Type Data
----                                                                                           ----              ---- ----
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\InstalledVersions\31ab5147-9a97-4452-8443-d9709f0516e1 SemanticVersion String 7.1.3
```

[image: Image displaying the specified key in the Windows Registry Editor]

As you can see, the version of PowerShell 7 installed on my computer is 7.1.3. If PowerShell 7 is **not** installed on the target computer, the key in its entirety should not exist.

As mentioned in the Microsoft documentation, the registry path will be slightly different dependent on installed PowerShell version.

Part of the key path changing could pose a challenge in some scenarios, but for those interested in a command line-based solution, PowerShell itself can handle this problem easily.

The PowerShell cmdlet used to query the data in this registry value is the [`Get-ItemPropertyValue` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue). Observe its use and output as follows (note the asterisk [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) character used in place of the part of the key path that is likely to change):

```
PS> Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\InstalledVersions\*" -Name "SemanticVersion"

7.1.3
```

Just a simple one-liner.

Answer (score 9):

`$host.version` is just plain wrong/unreliable. This gives you the version of the hosting executable (powershell.exe, powergui.exe, powershell_ise.exe, powershellplus.exe etc) and **not** the version of the engine itself.

The engine version is contained in `$psversiontable.psversion`. For PowerShell 1.0, this variable does not exist, so obviously if this variable is not available it is entirely safe to assume the engine is 1.0, obviously.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to forget this page and never return to it is to learn the `Get-Variable`:

```
Get-Variable | where {$_.Name -Like '*version*'} | %{$_[0].Value}
```

There is no need to remember every variable. Just `Get-Variable` is enough (and "There should be something about version").

Comment: Which is same as `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: Looking for the PS version? type $PSVersion [tab] [enter]. Done. Don't need to remember anything :)

Comment: this really only is useful if one is very familiar with the piping tricks that are used.  No way a beginner is going to be able to remember that all that syntax easier than just remembering $PSVersionTable

Comment: Guys, Get-Variable works well alone (if all what you need just to get the version), piping there is just a joke :) I do not remember piping syntax either.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
$psVersion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
If ($psVersion)
{
    #PowerShell Version Mapping
    $psVersionMappings = @()
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.1.14393.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5.1 Preview';ApplicableOS='Windows 10 Anniversary Update'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.1.14300.1000';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5.1 Preview';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 5'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10586.494';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows 10 1511 + KB3172985 1607'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10586.122';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows 10 1511 + KB3140743 1603'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10586.117';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 RTM 1602';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8.1, and Windows 7 SP1'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10586.63';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows 10 1511 + KB3135173 1602'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10586.51';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 RTM 1512';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8.1, and Windows 7 SP1'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10514.6';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 Production Preview 1508';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012 R2'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.10018.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 Preview 1502';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012 R2'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='5.0.9883.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 5 Preview November 2014';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='4.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 4 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8.1, and Windows 7 SP1'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='3.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 3 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8, and Windows 7 SP1'}
    $psVersionMappings += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name='2.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 2 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and Windows 7'}
    foreach ($psVersionMapping in $psVersionMappings)
    {
        If ($psVersion -ge $psVersionMapping.Name) {
            @{CurrentVersion=$psVersion;FriendlyName=$psVersionMapping.FriendlyName;ApplicableOS=$psVersionMapping.ApplicableOS}
            Break
        }
    }
}
Else{
    @{CurrentVersion='1.0';FriendlyName='Windows PowerShell 1 RTM';ApplicableOS='Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows XP'}
}
```

You can download the detailed script from *[How to determine installed PowerShell version](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-determine-installed-32de832c)*.

Comment: This breaks as soon as a version is not explicitly present in the hash table.

Answer (score 7):

To check if PowerShell is installed use:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1 Install ( = 1 )
```

To check if RC2 or RTM is installed use:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1 PID (=89393-100-0001260-00301) -- For RC2
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1 PID (=89393-100-0001260-04309) -- For RTM
```

Source: [this website](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/40/view.asp?id=10618).

Answer (score 7):

Since the most helpful answer didn't address the *if exists* portion, I thought I'd give one take on it via a quick-and-dirty solution. It relies on PowerShell being in the path [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) which is likely what you want. (Hat tip to the top answer as I didn't know that.) Paste this into a *text* file and name it

> Test Powershell Version.cmd

or similar.

```
@echo off
echo Checking powershell version...
del "%temp%\PSVers.txt" 2>nul
powershell -command "[string]$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major +'.'+ [string]$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor | Out-File ([string](cat env:\temp) + '\PSVers.txt')" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo Powershell is not installed. Please install it from download.Microsoft.com; thanks.
) else (
 echo You have installed Powershell version:
 type "%temp%\PSVers.txt"
 del "%temp%\PSVers.txt" 2>nul
)
timeout 15
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed to check the version of PowerShell and then run the appropriate code. Some of our servers run v5, and others v4. This means that some functions, like compress, may or may not be available.

This is my solution:

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 5) {
    #Execute code available in PowerShell 5, like Compress
    Write-Host "You are running PowerShell version 5"
}
else {
    #Use a different process
    Write-Host "This is version $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The below  cmdlet will return the PowerShell version.

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
```

Comment: `$PSVersionTable` is an automatic variable; an object.  It is not a cmdlet.

Answer (score 3):

This is the top search result for "Batch file get powershell version", so I'd like to provide a basic example of how to do conditional flow in a batch file depending on the powershell version

**Generic example**

```
powershell "exit $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"
if %errorlevel% GEQ 5 (
    echo Do some fancy stuff that only powershell v5 or higher supports
) else (
    echo Functionality not support by current powershell version.
)
```

**Real world example**

```
powershell "exit $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"
if %errorlevel% GEQ 5 (
    rem Unzip archive automatically
    powershell Expand-Archive Compressed.zip
) else (
    rem Make the user unzip, because lazy
    echo Please unzip Compressed.zip prior to continuing...
    pause
)
```

Comment: I love the premise of this.  I never thought to return a "non-error" value in this way as an exit code.  The only thing I'd worry about here is what %errorlevel% could be when anything unexpected goes wrong, like powershell is not on the path, or `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major` can't be resolve (which would happen on PS v1), etc.?

Comment: Yes, good point. This solution is certainly naive in that aspect. In our organization, we were certain that only v4 and v5 were in play.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on `version 7.1.0` and it worked:

```
$PSVersionTable | Select-Object PSVersion
```

***Output***

```
PSVersion
---------
7.1.0
```

It doesn't work on `version 5.1` though, so rather go for this on versions below 7:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

***Output***

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  1171
```

***EDIT***

As of PowerShell 7.2.5, you can now do:

```
pwsh -v
```

Or

```
pwsh --version
```

***Output***

```
PowerShell 7.2.5
```

Comment: This appears to just repeat information already shared in multiple answers. Please only add new answers when there is *new* information.

Comment: @TylerH, would you mind pointing me to an answer with PowerShell 7? Scanning around, the last answer before mine was in 2016 and v7.1 is pretty new.

Comment: Your first solution essentially duplicates the answer from March 2014 by @Eclipses, and your second solution duplicates the accepted answer. If you wish to highlight that they do or don't work for PowerShell 7, perhaps add a comment to those answers instead.

Comment: @Bren0man, the command wording in @Eclipses' version (`Get-Host | Select-Object Version`) alone is enough to make it different. Plus I don't know whether there was Powershell 7 in 2014. Second version may be a duplicate just to keep alternatives in one place but my main point is in the first version.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following, which works on PS 7 and PS 5:

```
$psver = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
```

or:

```
$psver = (Get-Host).Version.Major
```

Then I can use logic depending on which version is running.

```
$PSVer = (Get-Host).Version.Major
$sortSwitch = "-Descending"
if ($PSVer -gt 5) {$sortSwitch = "-r"}
$pathSep = [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar

$pattern = "???? something.zip"
$files = (Get-ChildItem $pattern -Name | sort $sortSwitch)
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the "host" command from the PowerShell commandline. It should give you the value of the `$host` variable.

Comment: This is semi-wrong.  `host` resolves to `Get-Host`.  Regardless, it is not a reliable way to get the version.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but still relevant, it's just that the nature of the problem is different now in 2023.  Finding the version is easy, but first we have to launch the right executable.  For that, we're basically back to looking in the registry.

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1" /v Install >nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  :: Default to PowerShell 5 if both are installed
  set PSEXE=powershell
) else (
  set PSEXE=pwsh
)
echo Using %PSEXE%
%PSEXE% -ExecutionPolicy bypass -command "& { ... ; exit $LASTEXITCODE }"
```

There are other hints you can get by inspecting environment variables, but I think testing the registry for 'Windows' PowerShell is the safest.

Answer (score -2):

Extending the answer with a select operator:

```
Get-Host | select {$_.Version}
```

Comment: The accepted answer states *"... $Host.Version and (Get-Host).Version are not reliable - they reflect the version of the host only, not the engine"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen looks like my answer was before accepted answer

Comment: @HaBo What are you looking at? The accepted answer is from 2009.

Comment: @TylerH so what? I am not following your question. my answer clearly says its a extension to the accepted answer. its a simplified version.

Comment: @HaBo Your previous comment reads like you're justifying your answer by the fact that it was posted before the accepted answer, which is not at all the case. Your answer was posted 7 years after the accepted answer, and 6 years after the answer yours actually 'extends'; speaking of which, your answer does not clearly say it's an extension of the *accepted* answer (which doesn't even use `Get-Host`).

Answer (score -2):

I have made a small batch script that can determine PowerShell version:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('powershell -Command Get-Host ^| findstr /c:Version') do (echo %%a)
```

This simply extracts the version of PowerShell using `Get-Host` and searches the string `Version`

When the line with the version is found, it uses the `for` command to extract the version. In this case we are saying that the delimiter is a colon and search next the first colon, resulting in my case `5.1.18362.752`.