# Path to Powershell.exe (v 2.0)

Tags: powershell, path

Where is the Powershell (version 2.0) located? What is the path to Powershell.exe? I have Windows Server 2008 and Powershell installed. When I look at this folder:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell> dir


    Directory: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         20.4.2010     17:09            v1.0
```

I have only Powershell v1.0. But when I type

```
PS C:\> $Host.version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1


PS C:\>
```

It shows that I have v2.0 installed.

Comment: The "v1.0" you see above is just a directory name, not an actual version number.

Comment: Just look at PowerShell link's target location

Answer (score 208, accepted):

I believe it's in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\`. In order to confuse the innocent, MS kept it in a directory labeled "v1.0". Running this on Windows 7 and checking the version number via `$Host.Version` ([Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed)) shows it's 2.0.

Another option is type `$PSVersionTable` at the command prompt. If you are running v2.0, the output will be:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4927
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

If you're running version 1.0, the variable doesn't exist and there will be no output.

Localization PowerShell version 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0:

- 64 bits version: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
- 32 bits version: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: Maybe it was a case of hard-coded paths that they wanted to preserve compatibility with? _Microsoft being Microsoft_

Comment: "In order to confuse the innocent" is going to be one of my favourite quotes.

Comment: That's like putting 64-bit apps in the "system32" folder which they do as well.

Answer (score 66):

I think $PsHome has the information you're after?

```
PS .> $PsHome
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

PS .> Get-Help about_automatic_variables

TOPIC
    about_Automatic_Variables ...
```

Answer (score 42):

Here is one way...

```
(Get-Process powershell | select -First 1).Path
```

Here is possibly a better way, as it returns the first hit on the path, just like if you had ran Powershell from a command prompt...

```
(Get-Command powershell.exe).Definition
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is a better answer than the one currently voted up to 35.  The original question seemed to be about the path to the executable, with version information being incidental to the question.  This answer directly addresses that question, bypassing even the "supposed to be" answer and letting a person find out exactly where the exe is on their own system, even if that system differs from default.  (This is what I came here looking for, so I appreciate it.)

Comment: Searching based on the executable being `powershell.exe` is a little too relaxed, since you could easily rename another executable to `powershell.exe`, and have it pick up that process instead. `Get-Process -Id $PID` would work, though I'm not sure what version `$PID` was introduced in.

Comment: I see your "too relaxed" point, however, using the $PID will return the current host, which may not be a Powershell interpreter. Like Powershell_ise.exe, for instance.

Comment: maybe since November 2011 properties have changed. 
For me (in July 2016, using Windows Server 2012) the property .Source does not exist, Instead, I can use the property .Definition which returns: 
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe".

   My $PSHome variable contains: 
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
Also, if you use get-process, consider using 'powershell*' instead of just powershell, in case you are using powershell_ise.
HTH

Comment: Changed answer from using .Source to .Definition.

Comment: @NathanHartley why is it called `definition` and not `source` (the displayed column name) ?

Comment: Interesting. There have been some changes over the years. It seems, that property started as Source, changed to Definition and is now (tested in v5.1) available via both Source and Destination.

Comment: With Get-Process you have to be careful that you get the correct architecture. It's possible to get the path to 64-bit PowerShell when you are running from 32-bit PowerShell, depending on what processes are running. (There's also the possibility of renaming random executables as "powershell" as @CharlesGrunwald points out.)

Comment: With Get-Command you always get the path to 64-bit PowerShell, although I think Microsoft auto-converts the folder name to the correct architecture (not sure of the details there).

Answer (score 13):

It is always C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0. It was left like that for backward compability is what I heard or read somewhere.

Comment: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe. In case SystemRoot is not "C:\Windows"

Comment: This isn't true for 32-bit PowerShell on 64-bit Windows. In that case, it is located at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.

Answer (score 13):

To get the complete path to the currently running PowerShell, you can use this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

The resulting path includes the PowerShell executable filename, which allows you to distinguish between PowerShell and PowerShell ISE (unlike $PsHome, which only shows you the PowerShell folder). Also, unlike Get-Process, it is not affected by
other processes running on the system, so you always get the correct path for the current architecture (32-bit or 64-bit).

The [GetCurrentProcess method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess?view=net-5.0) is available from .NET Framework 1.1 and .NET Core 1.0, so this should work on any version of .NET/PowerShell.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue but it turned out to be an issue related to path.
In my computer in Windows folder too an additional copy of powershell.exe is installed.  Please check the path variable to get which .exe is called.