# How to seperate lines of .bat when encrypted from powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a 10KB powershell script that I am trying to convert to a .bat. The format of the script is 
1. declare constants 2. a bunch of for each child item loops involving the sending of an email and the moving of a file. Other bat files that I have made do work.

There are 6 non-nested loops.
When the bat of each loop is run in isolation (with the declarations), everything works. When I combine 3, one group works, the other sends the email without moving the file. When all  are combined, nothing works and command prompt window doesn't even pop up.

I read that the line length limit of a bat file is 127 bytes (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69563) and I think that this is the cause of my problem. Do I need to do something in powershell to separate the lines so the bat file won't try to read it as one line?

To convert, I used the script from here (http://www.altitudeintegration.com/PowerShellToBatFile.aspx)

Comment: You'll notice that the "applies to" section on that page are all DOS versions, not `CMD`. I believe that there is no 127-byte limit under `CMD`. Unlikely that *that* alone is causing the problem. Try turning `echo` on at a place you know the procedure is reaching, then add a `pause` statement at another point after your problem section. This will restrict the amount of diagnostic displayed and may assist you in tracing the problem.

Comment: What do you actually mean with `encrypted` in the title? Don't you mean `converted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the original PowerShell script from a batch file using

> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File myscript.ps1

This way you can use your script by doubleclicking on the batch file.

The `ExecutionPolicy` parameter can be used to allow the script to run, without altering the machine level ExecutionPolicy:

> Sets the default execution policy for the current session and saves it
>   in the $env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference environment variable. This
>   parameter does not change the Windows PowerShell execution policy that
>   is set in the registry.

This way there is no need to convert the PowerShell scripts to batch (which may not be possible at all).

You can use `powershell.exe /?` from a command prompt to discover all it's options.

Note that PowerShell defaults to setting the ExecutionPolicy to `Restricted` (`RemoteSigned` in Windows Server 2012 R2). Changing the machine wide policy in machine scope requires local admin rights.

Using the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter on `powershell.exe` sets the executionpolicy for the local scope only.

See more details on ExecutionPolicy using

> Get-Help about_Execution_Policies

or look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh847748.aspx

You can find the PowerShell.exe executable in

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powersell.exe

(see: [Path to Powershell.exe (v 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4145232/62662) )

Comment: Unfortunately, the computer has a high security policy and I cannot run a saved PS script; I can only select the code in the ISE and run the selection.

Comment: @ClintEastwood That seems a rather shortsighted security policy to me. What harm could a PowerShell script do, that a .bat file or executable cannnot?

Comment: Its not that they specifically disabled ps scripts. Don't off the shelf computers come with running ps scripts disabled until you change the permissions? I can't change the permissions away from the default because I am not the admin.

Comment: It was helpful and I can run some scripts like this, but this script is not working when called by a bat.

Comment: Of the answers, this was the best because it tells me how I need to phrase my next question, which I will do when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the entire answer to your question, but I specifically wanted to address your 127-byte assertion.  That may have been true for 16-bit DOS, but `cmd.exe` has no such limitation.

#### test case:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "longline=############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################"

call :length %longline% len

echo longline is %len% bytes

:: end main script
goto :EOF

:length <string> <var_to_set>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "str=%~1"
for /l %%I in (1,1,1000) do (
    if "!str!"=="!str:~-%%I!" (
        endlocal && set "%~2=%%I"
        goto :EOF
    )
)
```

#### output:

> longline is 300 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Did you originally script or code the bat file?

If not, can you pull that file out of backup?

I know we used to encode our KiX Scripts, so you should have the magic decoder ring as it were.  Personally, I would be very careful in encoding your scripts unless they include login credentials.  Other than that, I would leave them as raw text.

Thanks!

Comment: I started with a powershell script (which works perfectly) but I needed it to be something one can click on because there are high security settings on the the computer and I can't run saved ps scripts by clicking on them. I used a bat maker I found online

Comment: If the security settings of your environment prevent you from getting work done, then those settings are wrong (for lack of a better word). PowerShell is no more a security risk than `BAT` files and with script signing available to validate that scripts haven't been tampered with, can be *more* secure.

Comment: Preachin' to the choir