# Open PowerShell with Shift+Ctrl+C instead of Cmd

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I would like to open a PowerShell window (outside of VSC) with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

By default, this shortcut will open a `cmd.exe`, so I would like to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `terminal.external.windowsExec` setting in settings.json. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982778/5990435) to find PowerShell's executable path if yours isn't the default one.

```json
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Comment: But I wanted to open the terminal outside of VSC, not the integrated terminal, as explained in the question.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't able to test it immediately, I had read about them sharing the same setting but that was before 1.6.1. I found the other setting and edited my answer ; you can use `terminal.external.windowsExec`.