# 'grep' in PowerShell 1.0

Tags: powershell, grep

I want to find files containing the word "navbar" anywhere in files. I can do this using Mac's grep command like this:

```
grep -R "navbar" *
```

What's its equivalent in PowerShell 1.0?

Comment: Just an FYI, the path %windir%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0 doesn't mean you have powershell 1.0 - this is an unfortunate side effect of an earlier botched versioning decision. This is the location for powershell 1, 2 and 3 (the latest as of right now.) - to see the powershell version, examine $psversiontable variable. If it does not exist, you have 1.0. If it does exist, look at the PSVersion property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
findstr /s "navbar" *
```

It's a native command but should work well enough.

PowerShell 1.0 itself is a little tricky, as `Select-String` (the direct equivalent) only exists since 2.0, I think. So you'd have to make do with something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_
    ($_ | Get-Content) -cmatch 'navbar' |
      ForEach-Object { $file.Name + ':' + $_ }
  }
```

Short version:

```
ls -r|%{$f=$_;($_|gc)-cmatch'navbar'|%{$f.Name+":$_"}}
```

This is quite literally:

1. Find all files recursively (the `-R` part).
2. Read each file and print matching lines with their file name.

Comment: Erm, poor users of outdated software. Install PowerShell v2 please. And `findstr` *works*. The rest was just to emulate its output. If you're only interested in the file where `navbar` appears (and not the line where it does) then `gci -r|?{(gc $_)-cmatch'navbar'}` does that.

Comment: Just an FYI, the path %windir%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0 doesn't mean you have powershell 1.0 - this is an unfortunate side effect of an earlier botched versioning decision. This is the location for powershell 1, 2 and 3 (the latest as of right now.) - to see the powershell version, examine $psversiontable variable. If it does not exist, you have 1.0. If it does exist, look at the PSVersion property

Comment: Additionally, you could only have 1.0 if you're running server 2003 or windows xp (which I hope you're not!)

Comment: To determine the PowerShell version, see Stack Overflow question *[How to determine what version of PowerShell is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed)*.