# Read txt file in folder and fint some text by per sample

Tags: powershell

I try to read big data log file, in folder C: \ log \ 1 \ i put 2 txt files, i need open-> read all file .txt and find with filter some text like whis: [text]

```
# Filename: script.ps1


$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\log\1\" -Filter "*.txt"
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $StringMatch = $null
    $StringMatch = select-string $File -pattern "[Error]"
    if ($StringMatch) {out-file -filepath C:\log\outputlog.txt -inputobject $StringMatch}
}
    # end of script
```

not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['grep' in PowerShell 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113113/grep-in-powershell-1-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would doing something like a select-string work?

```
Select-String C:\Scripts\*.txt -pattern "SEARCH STRING HERE" | Format-List
```

Or if there are multiple files you are wanting to parse maybe use the same select-string but within a loop and output the results.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\log\1\" -Filter "*.txt"
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $StringMatch = $null
    $StringMatch = select-string $File -pattern "SEARCH STRING HERE"
    if ($StringMatch) {out-file -filepath c:\outputlog.txt -inputobject $StringMatch}
}
```

Comment: There are several txt files in a folder, these files I need to find TWO LINES:
[Error]  and [File] (braces mandatory)

Answer (score 0):

This will print out the file name along with the line number in the file.  I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\log\outlog.txt
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\log\1\" -Filter "*.txt"
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $lineNumber = 0
    $content = Get-Content -Path "C:\log\1\$File"
    foreach($line in $content)
    {
        if($line.Contains('[Error]'))
        {
            Add-Content -Path C:\log\outlog.txt -Value "$File -> $lineNumber"
        }
        $lineNumber++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below works

It selects strings in txt files in your folder based on -SimpleMatch and then appends it to new.txt file.

Though i do not know how to put two simple matches in one line. Maybe someone does and can post it here

```
Select-String   -Path C:\log\1\*.txt -SimpleMatch "[Error]" -ca  | select -exp line | out-file C:\log\1\new.txt -Append
Select-String   -Path C:\log\1\*.txt -SimpleMatch "[File]" -ca  | select -exp line | out-file C:\log\1\new.txt -Append
```

Regards

-----edit-----

If you want to you may not append it anywhere just display - simply dont pipe it to out-file

Answer (score 0):

use index then check it :

```
New-Item C:\log\outputlog.txt
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\log\1\" -Include "*.txt"
foreach ($File in $Files)
{

    $StringMatch = $null
    $StringMatch = Get-Content $File  
    if($StringMatch.IndexOf("[Error]") -ne -1)
    {
        Add-Content -Path C:\log\outputlog.txt -Value ($StringMatch+"
        -------------------------------------------------------------
        ")
    }
}
    # end of script
```