# How to ensure that we are using powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We are providing scripts to clients that will be working only in Powershell 2.0.

Through command we can ensure that powershell 2.0 is installed like below

```
$version = Get-host | Select-object Version
```

But if we provide script how to ensure that they are executing it from Powershell 2.0?

When executing the script , Powershell 2.0 features may give script errors while initiating the script itself.Isn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can annotate your script with [`#requires`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765) and state that it shouldn't run on anything less than PowerShell v2:

```
#requires -Version 2.0
```

<sub>(Side note: This is surprisingly hard to find even if you know vaguely that it exists.)</sub>

Comment: Do you mean to say that it should be added as first line in my script in order to prevent it from working in 1.0?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: read this about Requirments: http://tfl09.blogspot.de/2009/01/more-in-powershells-require-statement.html

Comment: Added a link to the actual documentation.

Comment: The #Requires specifies a MINIMUM version - Not a specific version. Thus #Requires -version 2.0 will succeed in a version 3.o environment.

Comment: Indeed and that's what I stated in my answer as well. Most of the time you *do* want a minimum version, though, because you're using stuff that older versions don't have. Read their question and they just want this so that their scripts refuse to run on PS1 because they're using PS2 features.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on the host version is not the safest thing to do as the script can be run on hosts that do not have the same host version as PowerShell's version.

The $PSVersionTable variable was added in v2. You can check if the variable exists, if it does you're running v2 and above, you can also check PSVersion.Major property:

```
if($PSVersionTable)
{
    'PowerShell {0}' -f $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
}
else
{
   'PowerShell 1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
# get version
$ver = $PsVersionTable.psversion.major
 # Check to see if it's V2

If ($ver -NE 2) 
   {"incorrect version - exiting; return}
# Everything that follows is V2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$PSVersionTable`

You will get something like:

```
    Name                           Value
    ----                           ----- 
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5456 
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514 
PSVersion                      2.0 
WSManStackVersion              2.0 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0} 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: Note that `$PSVersionTable` is absent in v1. It's a good indicator, but a naïve check just for the `PSVersion` property will not do alone.

Comment: @Joey: your right, i found this thread guess its what the OP needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed