# How check if install Powershell

Tags: c#

I write program on c#. I need set trigger, that check: if installed Azure PowerShell or not. So how it write? If exist unique path for Azure PowerShell? Or better see on register?

Comment: are you looking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed

Answer (score 0):

One way to check the installation status/version of Azure Powershell is to type this cmdlet in your PowerShell session.

Get-module azure

If you mean to check it programmatically from code, I believe registry is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. You can try to do like this, maybe it help you:

```
try
            {
                var pipe = PowerShell.Create().AddScript("Get-Module -ListAvailable" +
                    " | Where-Object{ $_.Name -like 'Azure*' }" +
                    "|Select Version, Name, Author, PowerShellVersion").AddCommand("out-string");
                Collection<PSObject> results = pipe.Invoke();

                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                        Console.ReadKey();


                }



            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```