# Powershell asking to update to version 2.0 despite of having 3.0 installed

Tags: powershell

Both of my servers (remote and local) have Powershell 3.0 installed, however running the script below on it is giving me a warning message asking to update to version 2.0. The strange thing is that (Get-Host).Version is giving me different values whether the command is executed locally or remotely (Please see notes below for example)

this is my powershell script:

```
$Uri = "http://" + $ExternalHost + ":5985"
$username = $Domain + "\********"

# Setup and start remote session
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "********"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pw
$session = new-pssession -ConnectionUri $Uri -credential $cred

$report = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 
    Add-PSSnapin -Name VeeamPSSnapIn -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $sessionVMSummary = @()
    get-vbrjob | foreach{   
        $session = $_.findlastsession(); 
        if (($session -ne $NULL) -and ($_.isScheduleEnabled -eq $TRUE)) {
            $Info = [Veeam.Backup.Core.CBackupTaskSession]::GetByJobSession($session.id) | select -Property ObjectName, Reason, QueuedTime, Status
            $sessionDocument = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                "Name" = $session.Name
                "Result" = $session.Result
                "CreationTime" = $session.CreationTime
                "EndTime" = $session.EndTime
                "JobType" = $session.JobType
                "ObjectStatus" = $Info
            }
            $sessionVMSummary +=  $sessionDocument
        }
    }

    return $sessionVMSummary
}
```

and this is what $ExternalHost is returning:

```
"WARNING: You should update your PowerShell to PowerShell 2.0 version. <== I NEED TO GET RID OF THIS WARNING MESSAGE
[
{
    "Name":  ********,
    "CreationTime":  "\/Date(1402290392717)\/",
    "ObjectStatus":  {
                         "ObjectName":  ********,
                         "Reason":  "",
                         "QueuedTime":  "\/Date(1402290405917)\/",
                         "Status":  {
                                        "value":  0,
                                        "Value":  "Success"
                                    }
                     },
    "Result":  {
                   "value":  0,
                   "Value":  "Success"
               },
    "EndTime":  "\/Date(1402291286497)\/",
    "JobType":  {
                    "value":  0,
                    "Value":  "Backup"
                },
    "PSComputerName":  ********,
    "RunspaceId":  "ad3ea82d-48dd-4135-9648-8bf3bba75e46",
    "PSShowComputerName":  true
}
]
"
```

**NOTE:** Somehow I am get different build version

I get PS version 3 on the local server
    PS C:\Users\ea_admin> (Get-Host).Version

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

And I get PS version 1 on same server running (Get-Host).Version remotely:
    Invoke-Command -Session $session {
        return (Get-Host).Version
    }

```
"Major":  1,
"Minor":  0,
"Build":  0,
"Revision":  0,
"MajorRevision":  0,
"MinorRevision":  0,
"PSComputerName":  "remote.servertest.com",
"RunspaceId":  "23634ba8-bfe3-4242-8593-bed3d9aa8ad1",
"PSShowComputerName":  true
```

**QUESTION:** Why am I getting different versions?

Comment: Can you post the error you're receiving?

Comment: What version of Powershell is installed on $ExternalHost?  You mentioned that "your server has Powershell 3.0 installed" but there are two servers here - the server where you running this script, and the server referenced in $ExternalHost.

Comment: sorry @TimFerrill and JamesQMurphy , I have updated my question with the returning data from the external host to show the Warning message. Also both my powershell servers have Powershell 3.0 installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed