# How to determine which version of PowerShell is installed on a PC

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script which check the version of PowerShell. If it's version 4 then proceed, otherwise stop the execution. What I am trying to achieve here is I have five scripts in a folder which are run in order. I would like to put a PowerShell script right at the top which checks the version.

Here is my code:

```
$psversion= $psversiontable
if($psversion -eq 4.0)
{
    ./01. Run All Script.ps1
}
```

"Run All Script" runs the rest of the scripts in order, so I would like to give PowerShell script as `02. check_psversion.ps1`

```
requires -version 4
write-host "this is your version"
```

Comment: `requires` **must** have a hash mark (`#`) in front of it.

Comment: Related post - [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825585/465053)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to write any `if` tests; use the [`requires`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765.aspx) directive in all of your scripts (never assume or depend upon execution order, be explicit in each script).

```
#requires -version 4
```

If you attempt to execute the script on version 3 or earlier, it will stop because of the `requires` directive.

Edit: To get the Powershell version number, use `$psversiontable.psversion.major`, unless you need finer resolution (exact build number).

Comment: i created a dummy script with two line requires -version 5 and than a write host line but i am getting this error requires is not recognized as the name of cmdlet

Comment: Did you prefix `requires` with `#`? That's required as well, as seen in the examples in the link (and the code) I gave.

Comment: its running thanks, but i didnt understand # is for comments how come its running as a command or directives

Comment: In this context, it's not a comment.