# Determine PowerShell version remotely via WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting

I have searched here and elsewhere and could not find an answer, so here is my question.

What is the best way to determine PowerShell version on a remote computer using WMI?

**Background**

My task is to audit and update some 1000 servers to recent version of PowerShell. Some of them have PowerShell v1 and some do not have WinRM configured, so **Invoke-command** is not an option. **PSExec** is also not an option in this environment. This is why I need to use **WMI** for this task.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After much research I'm still leaning towards WMI. In particular retrieving the file version of "powershell.exe". This seems to me to be the only way to cover all versions.

Code I have so far is here:

```
$path = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe" 
$query = "SELECT Version FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Name = '$path'" 
$PSFileVer = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -ComputerName $servername -Credential $creds 
$BuildVer = [version]$PSFileVer.Version.Split()[0]
```

All I need now is a comprehensive list, mapping file version (build number) to powershell version. Any Ideas?

Comment: How about using a management tool like System Center Configuration Manager? Managing more than a few dozen servers without good tools is waste of time.

Comment: SCCM is an option, but only covers about 80% of the servers. Another reason why I'm looking for a PowerShell/WMI solution.

Comment: How about [registry keys](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17142839/503046), then?

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks. *"Microsoft's recommended forward compatible method"* unfortunately breaks down with version 3 of PowerShell. It's still a viable option if you stick with version 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/7f6e0eca-5e4a-46be-a19e-60292ed64f69/win32process-remote-execution-and-getting-output) is

```
$command = "ipconfig/all > C:\temp\result.txt"
$cmd = "cmd /c $command"

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $cmd -ComputerName "remotepc"
sleep 1
Get-Content \\remotepc\C$\temp\result.txt
```

You can also do similar via [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/77585/execute-program-on-remote-computer-using-powershell) method. If you do so, you can't get the return value directly, u must redirect to a file.

You could setup share for the results instead of putting result on local machine

Comment: Thanks @majkinetor. That is definitely a plausible way to execute code on remote PC via WMI. Although I really don't like using .tmp files to get results, I might end up using this if I don't come up with a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps here is the command :

```
$command = "powershell -command "+'"$PSVersionTable.PsVersion.Major | out-file c:\temp\version.txt"'
```