# Iterating through a JSON file PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to loop through the below JSON file in PowerShell.

Without specifically naming the top tags (e.g. 17443 and 17444), as I do not know them in advance I cannot find a way to loop through the data.

I want to output tags 3, 4 and 5 (title, firstname, surname) for all the records.

How would I accomplish that?

```
{
   "17443":{
      "sid":"17443",
      "nid":"7728",
      "submitted":"1436175407",
      "data":{
         "3":{
            "value":[
               "Mr"
            ]
         },
         "4":{
            "value":[
               "Jack"
            ]
         },
         "5":{
            "value":[
               "Cawles"
            ]
         }
      } },
      "17444":{
         "sid":"17444",
         "nid":"7728",
         "submitted":"1436891400",
         "data":{
            "3":{
               "value":[
                  "Miss"
               ]
            },
            "4":{
               "value":[
                  "Charlotte"
               ]
            },
            "5":{
               "value":[
                  "Tann"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "17445":{
         "sid":"17445",
         "nid":"7728",
         "submitted":"1437142325",
         "data":{
            "3":{
               "value":[
                  "Mr"
               ]
            },
            "4":{
               "value":[
                  "John"
               ]
            },
            "5":{
               "value":[
                  "Brokland"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

I can access the data with the code below, but I want to avoid putting in 17443, 17444, etc.

```
$data = ConvertFrom-Json $json

foreach ($i in $data.17443)
{
   foreach ($t in $i.data.3)
   {
      Write-Host $t.value
   }
   foreach ($t in $i.data.4)
   {
      Write-Host $t.value
   }
   foreach ($t in $i.data.5)
   {
      Write-Host $t.value
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can get to the data by specifically adding the top tags, e.g

         foreach ($i in $data.17443)
         {
            foreach ($t in $i.data.3)
            {
               write-host $t.value
            }
           foreach ($t in $i.data.4)
            {
               write-host $t.value
            }
          foreach ($t in $i.data.5)
            {
               write-host $t.value
            }

         }

Comment: I've edited my question with this, so it is more helpful

Comment: That's a lot better. :) You should generally include the code that you have been working with, this gives others the chance to evaluate your approach and to work with something tangible.

Comment: Fixed the json.  There was a missing curly brace before ,"17444", and an extra one was at the end.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

## PowerShell 3.0+

In PowerShell 3.0 and higher (see: [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825585/)) you can use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet to convert a JSON string into a PowerShell data structure.

That's convenient and unfortunate at the same time - convenient, because it's very easy to consume JSON, unfortunate because `ConvertFrom-Json` gives you [PSCustomObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscustomobject(v=vs.85).aspx), and they are hard to iterate over as key-value pairs.

When you know the keys then there is nothing to iterate - you just access them directly, e.g. `$result.thisKey.then.thatKey.array[1]`, and you're done.

But in this particular JSON, the keys seem to be dynamic/not known ahead of time, like `"17443"` or `"17444"`. That means we need something that can turn a `PSCustomObject` into a key-value list that `foreach` can understand.

```
# helper to turn PSCustomObject into a list of key/value pairs
function Get-ObjectMember {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
    )
    $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
        $key = $_.Name
        [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
    }
}
```

Now we can traverse the object graph and produce a list of output objects with `Title`, `FirstName` and `LastName`

```
$json = '{"17443": {"17444": {"sid": "17444","nid": "7728","submitted": "1436891400","data": {"3": {"value": ["Miss"]},"4": {"value": ["Charlotte"]},"5": {"value": ["Tann"]}}},"17445": {"sid": "17445","nid": "7728","submitted": "1437142325","data": {"3": {"value": ["Mr"]},"4": {"value": ["John"]},"5": {"value": ["Brokland"]}}},"sid": "17443","nid": "7728","submitted": "1436175407","data": {"3": {"value": ["Mr"]},"4": {"value": ["Jack"]},"5": {"value": ["Cawles"]}}}}'

$json | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-ObjectMember | foreach {
    $_.Value | Get-ObjectMember | where Key -match "^\d+$" | foreach {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Title = $_.value.data."3".value | select -First 1
            FirstName = $_.Value.data."4".value | select -First 1
            LastName = $_.Value.data."5".value | select -First 1
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Title                      FirstName                  LastName                 
-----                      ---------                  --------                 
Miss                       Charlotte                  Tann                     
Mr                         John                       Brokland
```

---

## PowerShell 2.0 / Alternative approach

An alternative approach that also works for PowerShell 2.0 (which does not support some of the constructs above) would involve using the .NET [JavaScriptSerializer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle the JSON:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
$JS = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

Now we can do a very similar operation—even a bit simpler than above, because JavaScriptSerializer gives you regular [Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), which are easy to iterate over as key-value pairs via the `GetEnumerator()` method:

```
$json = '{"17443": {"17444": {"sid": "17444","nid": "7728","submitted": "1436891400","data": {"3": {"value": ["Miss"]},"4": {"value": ["Charlotte"]},"5": {"value": ["Tann"]}}},"17445": {"sid": "17445","nid": "7728","submitted": "1437142325","data": {"3": {"value": ["Mr"]},"4": {"value": ["John"]},"5": {"value": ["Brokland"]}}},"sid": "17443","nid": "7728","submitted": "1436175407","data": {"3": {"value": ["Mr"]},"4": {"value": ["Jack"]},"5": {"value": ["Cawles"]}}}}'

$data = $JS.DeserializeObject($json)

$data.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
    $_.Value.GetEnumerator() | where { $_.Key -match "^\d+$" } | foreach {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Title = $_.Value.data."3".value | select -First 1
            FirstName = $_.Value.data."4".value | select -First 1
            LastName = $_.Value.data."5".value | select -First 1
        }
    }
}
```

The output is the same:

```
Title                      FirstName                  LastName                 
-----                      ---------                  --------                 
Miss                       Charlotte                  Tann                     
Mr                         John                       Brokland
```

If you have JSON larger than 4 MB, set the [`JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx) accordingly.

---

## On reading JSON from files

If you read from a file, use `Get-Content -Raw -Encoding UTF-8`.

- `-Raw` because otherwise `Get-Content` returns an array of individual lines and `JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject` can't handle that. Recent Powershell versions seem to have improved type-conversion for .NET function arguments, so it might not error out on your system, but if it does (or just to be safe), use `-Raw`.
- `-Encoding` because it's wise to specify a text file's encoding when you read it and `UTF-8` is the most probable value for JSON files.

---

## Notes

- When you build JSON that contains items with unpredictable keys, prefer an array structure like `{items: [{key: 'A', value: 0}, {key: 'B', value: 1}]}` over `{'A': 0, 'B': 1}`. The latter seems more intuitive, but it's both harder to generate and harder to consume.
- `ConvertFrom-Json()` gives you a PowerShell custom object (`PSCustomObject`) that reflects the data in the JSON string.
- You can loop though the properties of a custom object with `Get-Member -type NoteProperty`
- You can access the properties of an object dynamically using the `$object."$propName"` syntax, alternatively `$object."$(some PS expression)"`.
- You can create your own custom object and initialize it with a bunch of properties with `New-Object PSObject -Property @{...}`, alternatively `[PSCustomObject]@{ .. }`
  `

Comment: great answer.
it's infuriating that this very common task is so clunky in powershell.

Comment: @orionelenzil It's a common design anti-pattern in JSON to structure data with non-predictable keys (a.k.a. *"this should have been an array"*). It's a pain in all languages, some more, some less. Using sane data structures helps a lot.

Comment: The alternative approach worked fine for me, I just needed to parse some JSON. Note the syntax for loading from a file (path in a variable $f) is: `$json = Get-Content $f -Raw -Encoding "UTF8"`

Answer (score 10):

This question comes up a lot. In this case, we have to loop over properties twice.  This is my current answer.  Make the object a little easier to work with.  Both the top level and the data properties become arrays of "name" and "value".  You could use select-object calculated properties to present it any way you want.  It seems like in JSON you more often get random properties, rather than an array of the same properties.

```
$a = cat file.json | convertfrom-json

$a = $a.psobject.properties | select name,value 
$a | foreach { $_.value.data = 
  $_.value.data.psobject.properties | select name,value }

$a.value.data.value

value
-----
{Mr}
{Jack}
{Cawles}
{Miss}
{Charlotte}
{Tann}
{Mr}
{John}
{Brokland}
```

Trying something similar with jq:

```
'{"prop1":1, "prop2":2, "prop3":3}' | jq to_entries | convertfrom-json

key    value
---    -----
prop1     1
prop2     2
prop3     3
```

Also, convertFrom-Json in Powershell 7 has an -AsHashTable parameter, that gives you keys and values properties.

```
$a = '{"name":"joe","address":"here"}' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$a

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           joe
address                        here

$a.keys
name
address

$a.values
joe
here
```

Comment: `-AsHashTable` was the answer for me!

Answer (score 7):

This task can be solved without resorting to the construction of a rocket, as described in the comments above =)

To iterate over a json file, we can refer to a variable that is a powershell object (into which we considered json)

See what $data.PsObject.Properties there are a lot of interesting things there =)

Decision:

```
$data = ConvertFrom-Json $json

foreach ($elem in $data.PsObject.Properties.Value)
{
    Write-Host "Title:" $elem.data.3.value
    Write-Host "First Name:" $elem.data.4.value
    Write-Host "Surname:" $elem.data.5.value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, we'll use `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet to convert a JSON string into a PowerShell data structure.

Then, to illustrate how to loop through the nested PowerShell data structure, we'll demonstrate it with a simplified example.

**Given**

```
$response = [PSCustomObject] @{
    prediction = [PSCustomObject] @{
        cat = 0.6576587659
        dog = 0.3423412341
    }
}
```

Our goal is to iterate through the key-value pairs inside prediction (i.e. cat and dog) and shorten their values to 3 decimal places.

**Solve**

```
$response.prediction | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
    $key = $_.Name
    [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = "{0:N3}" -f $response.prediction.$key}
}
```

We first loop through all members of prediction and the then for each of them we assign a new member key and a 3-decimal place value.

**Output**

```
Key Value
--- -----
cat 0.658
dog 0.342
```

Answer (score -24):

Here's a simple regex-based solution. Assuming that `$sRawJson` contains your JSON input:

```
$oRegex = [Regex]'(?:(?<="[345]":\{"value"\:\["))[^"]+'
$cParts = $oRegex.Matches(($sRawJson -replace '\s')) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"
```

Joining parts to get full names:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cParts.Count / 3; $i++) { $cParts[($i * 3)..($i * 3 + 2)] -join ' ' }
```

Comment: You never ever want to touch JSON with regular expressions.