# Looping through JSON file with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

How do I loop through all items in a JSON file? The current code just writes all names on one big line:

```
Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\temp\Environments.Generic.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
```

**json file:**

```
[
   {
      "Name":"EnableRetry",
      "Description":"Enable retry for Webservice Task",
      "Type":"Boolean",
      "Sensitive":false,
      "Value":true
   },
   {
      "Name":"FolderStageFiles",
      "Description":"Location of stage files",
      "Type":"String",
      "Sensitive":false,
      "Value":"d:\\sources\\"
   },
   {
      "Name":"FtpPassword",
      "Description":"Secret FTP password",
      "Type":"String",
      "Sensitive":true,
      "Value":"Welcome1"
   }
]
```

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520699/iterating-through-json-file-powershell ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up Select-Object and a ForEach-Object:

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\temp\Environments.Generic.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$JSON | Select-Object -Property Name,Description,Type,Sensitive,Value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name $_.Value
}
```

Comment: Looks like a fine solution to me. Apologies for not coming back to you.

Comment: No problem, I took your code as a base and that helped me... Will post the complete code on my blog in a couple of days.

Comment: Here is the complete code if someone want to copy it: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2017/05/import-and-export-ssis-catalog.html

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\temp\Environments.Generic.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

`$JSON` will be a PowerShell object that contains a collection of objects with all of the properties defined in your JSON file.

Enter `$JSON` at the console and you'll see the contents of this object.

To access specific properties for specific items in the collection you could do (for example):

```
$JSON | Where {$_.Name -eq 'FolderStageFiles'} | Select -ExpandProperty Value
```

Comment: Is there something for looping through the set because I don't know the values of the json file... only the structure (Name, Description, Type, Sensitive and Value).
I want to loop through these records and add these values to an SSIS environment like http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2015/08/deploying-environments-and-variables.html