# Accessing JSON arrays in Powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have the below JSON variable in Powershell and want to loop through each array to return the total value only. For example, I would expect `$response2.results.daily[0]`, `...daily[1]` ... etc would allow me to access each array in the array but it seems i have to declare the specific array name ex '2020-05-10'?

Is there a better way to handle APIs through PS?

[image]

Comment: There definitely is a way to *improve* the response from that API, so it's easier to handle. Don't use an object (`{daily: {"5/10/2020": {"total": "$0.030"}}}`), Use an array (`{daily: [{date: "2020-05-10", "total": "$0.030"}, ...]}`). Changing the data layout will make your life easier on more than one front, if you have any control over the API.

Comment: This comes up a lot:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520699/iterating-through-a-json-file-powershell

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hidden `psobject` property to obtain the individual property names on the `$response2.results.daily` object, then use those to access each array:

```
# use psobject to enumerate the property names (ie. '5/10/2020')
$dates = $response2.results.daily.psobject.Properties.Name

# loop through the property names
$dailyStats = $dates |ForEach-Object {
  $date = $_
  # Add the name (= date) as a new "date" property to the object
  $response2.results.daily.$name |Select-Object @{Name='date';Expression={$name}},*
}
```

`$dailyStats` will now be an array of objects like:

```
date      total   sms-in sms-out suppress
----      -----   ------ ------- --------
5/10/2020 $31.770 102    2,016   1
5/9/2020  $0.060  4      0       0
etc...
```

---

> Is there a better way to handle APIs through PS?

No idea, given that we don't know how you obtained the response in the first place ¯\_(ツ)_/¯