# How to get key value pairs from json property with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am stuck on how to get key value pairs from a json file dynamically meaning without knowing the key value in advance.

I have this sample json file, in the real application I have about 20 json files with a couple of thousand automated test cases:

```
{
    "runOnMachines": "SERVER-01",
    "cases": [
    {
        "testName": "Google Chrome Install 84.0.4147.89",
        "testDescription": "Verifies Google Chrome is Installed 84.0.4147.89",
        "testFunction": "Find-ProgramVersion",
        "args": [
          {
            "programName" : "Firefox",
            "version"     : "79.0"
          }
        ],
        "expectedResult": "true"
      },
      {
        "testName": "Tera Term 4.105",
        "testDescription": "Tera Term 4.105",
        "testFunction": "Find-ProgramVersion",
        "args": [
          {
            "programName" : "Tera Term",
            "version"     : "4.105"     
          }
        ],
        "expectedResult": "true"
      }
    ]
}
```

Find-ProgramVersion is a helper function which searches for a program installed in control panel / programs installed through the registry, it returns true or false. (More info on that here [Winster](https://github.com/TheFern2/Winster) Is part of an automated [framework](https://github.com/TheFern2/ReadyServer) I built to test virtual machines on servers.

Long story short, I have this ugly code, that I am trying to clean up, but I can't find how to extract my args dynamically from a json file. As of now, each function I write on Winster module I have to come on this script and add it manually with the correct json properties.

```
if($jsonData[$i].testFunction -eq "Find-ProgramVersion")
{
    $command = $jsonData[$i].testFunction + " " + $jsonData[$i].args.programName + " " + 
    $jsonData[$i].args.version
}

if($jsonData[$i].testFunction -eq "Find-ProgramVersionGrep")
{
    $command = $jsonData[$i].testFunction + " " + $jsonData[$i].args.programName + " " + 
    $jsonData[$i].args.version
}
```

I've tried casting `jsonData[$i].args` to array, I've also tried using Name and Value from PsObject.Properties but that gives also other values I don't need inherited from PsObject

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $jsonData.Count; $i++)
{ 
    $jsonData[$i].args.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Name
        $_.Value
    }
}
```

Gives me:

```
Count
1
Length
1
LongLength
1
Rank
1
SyncRoot

programName version
----------- -------
Firefox     79.0   
IsReadOnly
False
IsFixedSize
True
IsSynchronized
False
Count
1
Length
1
LongLength
1
Rank
1
SyncRoot
Tera Term   4.105  
IsReadOnly
False
IsFixedSize
True
IsSynchronized
False
```

What I am hoping to get from jsonData[$i].args is some kind of iterable, where I can use forloop, but I haven't been able to make the below PsObject usable. And witthout knowing args names in advance since some functions have different numbers of args.

```
@{programName=Firefox; version=79.0} @{programName=Tera Term; version=4.105}
```

Comment: This is a common class of problems.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520699/iterating-through-a-json-file-powershell

Comment: I looked at answers on the link, and I still believe the answer I picked is the best. On the link he created this custom object, but then at the moment of retrieving he still called values with hard coded strings, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(@'
{
  "runOnMachines": "SERVER-01",
  "cases": [
  {
      "testName": "Google Chrome Install 84.0.4147.89",
      "testDescription": "Verifies Google Chrome is Installed 84.0.4147.89",
      "testFunction": "Find-ProgramVersion",
      "args": [
        {
          "programName" : "Firefox",
          "version"     : "79.0"
        }
      ],
      "expectedResult": "true"
    },
    {
      "testName": "Tera Term 4.105",
      "testDescription": "Tera Term 4.105",
      "testFunction": "Find-ProgramVersion",
      "args": [
        {
          "programName" : "Tera Term",
          "version"     : "4.105"     
        }
      ],
      "expectedResult": "true"
    }
  ]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json).cases | ForEach-Object {
  $_.testFunction + ' ' + (
    $_.args.ForEach( { 
        $_.PSObject.Properties.Value.ForEach( {
            if ($_.contains(' ')) {
              # contains spaces -> double-quote
              '"{0}"' -f $_
            }
            else {
              $_
            }
          })
      })
  ) -join ' '
}
```

The above returns the following:

```
Find-ProgramVersion Firefox 79.0
Find-ProgramVersion "Tera Term" 4.105
```

More work is needed if there are values with *embedded* `"` chars.

- `$_.args.ForEach` iterates over all elements of the `args` array.
- `$_.PSObject.Properties.Value.ForEach` iterates over all property values of each element.
- `$_.contains(' ')` tests each property value for the presence of at least one space character, in which case the value is enclosed in double quotes (`'"{0}"' -f $_`) in the overall command line that is being constructed (via the string constructed from the space-joined values with `-join ' '`).