# Powershell Parse Swagger Json

Tags: json, powershell-7.0

The following works to parse a Swagger json into resource, method, httptype but probably... the $path.Definition part is weirdly, how can i get $path.Definition to be an array not a string that i need to parse for the array symbol.

```
$json = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot/Test/example_swagger.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$paths = Get-Member -InputObject $json.paths -MemberType NoteProperty
$result = ""
foreach($path in $paths) {
    $elements = $path.Name.Substring(5).split("/") -join ","
    $httpmethods = $path.Definition.Substring($path.Definition.IndexOf("@{"))
    if ($httpmethods.Contains("get")) {
        $result += $elements + ", GET" + "`n"
    }
    if ($httpmethods.Contains("post")) {
        $result += $elements + ", POST" + "`n" #same methodnames different http methods
    }
}
$result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in my answer to [Iterating through a JSON file PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33520699/18771), the output of `ConvertFrom-Json` is hard to iterate over. This makes *"for each key in object"* and *"keys of object not known ahead of time"* kinds of situations more difficult to handle, but not impossible.

You need a helper function:

```
# helper to turn PSCustomObject into a list of key/value pairs
function Get-ObjectMember {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
    )
    $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
        $key = $_.Name
        [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
    }
}
```

with this, the approach gets a whole lot simpler:

```
$swagger = Get-Content -Path "example_swagger.json" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$swagger.paths | Get-ObjectMember | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        path = $_.Key
        methods = $_.Value | Get-ObjectMember | ForEach-Object Key
    }
}
```

Applied to the default Swagger file from https://editor.swagger.io/ as a sample, this is printed

```
path                     methods            
----                     -------            
/pet                     {post, put}        
/pet/findByStatus        get                
/pet/findByTags          get                
/pet/{petId}             {delete, get, post}
/pet/{petId}/uploadImage post               
/store/inventory         get                
/store/order             post               
/store/order/{orderId}   {delete, get}      
/user                    post               
/user/createWithArray    post               
/user/createWithList     post               
/user/login              get                
/user/logout             get                
/user/{username}         {delete, get, put}
```

Comment: Very nice. Any idea how you could use this to get the `name` and `description` for all the **`tags`**, using this?