# Iterating a json file from a string or object and running functions according to a key/value

Tags: powershell

I have a json file, test.json, like the below

```
[
{ "STORE":"2001", "UUID":"d7985d5f", "Clock1":"91", "Type":"IP" },
{ "STORE":"2002", "UUID":"821a0368", "Clock1":"92", "Type":"GT" }
]
```

And I am getting a comma-separated string as below

```
$StoreInput = "2001,2002"
$StoreArray = $StoreInput.Split(",")

$storemap = "location\test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

What I want to do is, read $StoreArray, check the Type of each store against $storemap, and run function according to the type, passing uuid and Clock1

```
if (type = IP) {
    Function1 -Clock $Clock1 (from the json) -UUID $UUID (from the json) #Value of 2001's
}
elseif (type = GT) {
    Function2 -Clock $Clock1 (from the json) -UUID $UUID (from the json) #Value of 2002's
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520699/iterating-through-a-json-file-powershell might be usefull

Comment: Thank you @KonstantinIvanov, got the answer from the same above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to make sure you actually read the *contents* of the json file:

```
$StoreInput = "2001,2002"
$StoreArray = $StoreInput.Split(",")

$storemap = Get-Content "location\test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Since `$storemap` is actually an array, iterating over it is as easy as piping to the `ForEach-Object` command:

```
$storemap |ForEach-Object {
    # $_ will contain the current item/row from the array
}
```

To test for equality between two values, use the `-eq` operator - `=` is *only for assignment* in PowerShell:

```
$storemap |ForEach-Object {
  if($_.type -eq 'IP') {
    function1 -Clock $_.clock1 -UUID $_.UUID
  }
  elseif($_.type -eq 'GT') {
    function2 -Clock $_.clock1 -UUID $_.UUID
  }
}
```

Since we're passing the exact same arguments no matter what, we can extract those values and place them in a [splatting table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) that we can then use for either function:

```
$storemap |ForEach-Object {
  # prepare the arguments to be passed to the function
  $paramArgs = @{
    Clock = $_.clock1
    UUID  = $_.UUID
  }

  # then decide which function to call...
  if($_.type -eq 'IP') {
    function1 @paramArgs
  }
  elseif($_.type -eq 'GT') {
    function2 @paramArgs
  }
}
```

If you want to filter the array so you only get stores with one of the IDs stored in `$storeArray`, use `Where-Object`:

```
$storemap |Where-Object STORE -in $storeArray |ForEach-Object { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mathias R. Jessen

Here, I want to iterate each store in $StoreArray and check it against $storemap. Is there any other way then running two For Loop for the same?

Comment: @LabaNingombam I've added a snippet showing how you can filter `$storemap` based on the values in `$storeArray` :)