powershell - How to find text in nested result
I have a script which will show all VMs in a host, how since this result is the output of RESTful API (JSON), the result is nested.
Output of the $Json variable -
{
    "ErrorAdditionalDetails":  null,
    "ErrorCode":  null,
    "ErrorMessage":  null,
    "Success":  true,
    "VirtualMachines":  [
                            {
                               "VirtualMachineName":  "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                            }
    ]
}


$json | Select-Object VirtualMachineName
The above command shows blank.
Result should be:
VirtualMachineName : xxxxxxxxxxx

| convertfrom-json

Thanks a lot JS2010
further :-
$resultobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
foreach ($res_json in $resultobj){
if ($res_json -contains "VirtualMachineName"){
Write-Host $res_json
}
}
It still shows whole result in a variable, tried to put it in foreach loop, but loop runs only once, and couldn't get all details (The output has multiple values)

That isn't an array at the top.  Search how to go through a series of properties like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520699/iterating-through-a-json-file-powershell



JSON is (structured) text, so in order to use OO techniques on it, you must first parse it into an object graph, which is what ConvertFrom-Json does.

See this answer for details.


You can then simply use dot notation (property access) to access the property of interest:


($json | ConvertFrom-Json).VirtualMachines

This will output the equivalent of [pscustomobject] @{ VirtualMachineName =   "xxxxxxxxxxx" }, i.e. a [pscustomobject] instance with a .VirtualMachineName property containing the value of interest.
To output just the property value ("xxxxxxxxxxx"), simply append .VirtualMachineName to the command above.
Note:

The top-level .VirtualMachines property is an array.

The way PowerShell's member-access enumeration works is that if the array contains just one element, you'll get that element itself as output; with two or more elements, you'll get all elements as an array ([object[]]).



Hello Mklement0, I am able to get the desired result.  The thing which takes time is the result already in json, and all I need to manage it rather than converting it. As found after conversion it doesn't show the option like - .VirtualMachines.VirtualmachineName.  Also Convertfrom gives error, convertto is working. Now without conversion, I can get result. Also using PS custom object I am able to sum up things (but currently they are in List order, need it in table order, like the above output which you shared in your response.

@BhupeshGautam: PowerShell decides based on the number of properties of the input object whether to use Format-List (>=5) or Format-Table (<=4) for display formatting. If you want to force table output, pipe to Format-Table explicitly.  I'm not sure what the rest of your comment is trying to say; with your sample JSON, ConvertFrom-Json works fine. The point of the conversion is that by parsing the JSON text into an object graph, easy extraction of property values is possible. If $json already is a [pscustomobject] graph, then you obviously needn't call ConvertFrom-Json.
