# Where does the version number in PowerShell title refer to?

Tags: powershell

In this post I found the way to detect the installed Powershell version: [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version).

When I type "powershell" into "Execute as" (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) the powershell opens with the title:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPoershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

However, the commands from the linked SO question deliver following output:

[image: powershell output]

So my question: Why is there `v1.0` in the title of the shell window whereas the other commands tell me that I have version 2?

Comment: As the answers to the linked question say, you have v2 since $PSVersionTable works for you. Your question title is misleading as your actual question really has nothing to do with finding out what version you have.

Comment: @DeanOC you are right, I changed it to a maybe better title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PowerShell version is `2`. The title shows the path to the PowerShell executeable. I think the reason why all new PowerShell version are located there (in `v1.0`) is because so many cmd scripts invoking some PowerShell code using this file path (e. g. Scheduled Tasks). But I may be wrong.

Another reason could be, that its not possible to run two different PowerShell Versions side-by-side.

Comment: Yes, `v1.0` in the filepath is for backwards comp. Lets not forget compiled code referencing it! :-) It was a bad idea for MS to version it since they wouldn't allow multiple version to be installed side-by-side (unlike .NET Framework). You have the same problem With the fileextenstions ps1, psd1, psm1