# PSVersion is not recognized

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

After installing powershell, i tried running  `PSVersionTable.PSVersion` and `PSVersionTable` to check the version, however i get the following error:
[image]

I did install `WMF-4.0` and the `.NET` framework versions before installing `WMF-v5`

Most posts point me to make sure i have `.NET` and `WMF-4.0` installed and i cant seem to find anything else.

Note I am Using windows 7

Comment: `$PSVersionTable.psversion` or `$PSVersionTable.psversion.major` for getting directly to the version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enter `$PsVersionTable`. It is a built in variable and you access variables via $.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to get the version is `$PSVersionTable`. It's a variable, not a call to anything.

Comment: THANK YOU so much, you are the best