# Powershell cannot manage Format-Hex

Tags: powershell

one question about ms powershell. I cannot use the Format-Hex command, it returns me an error.
Does it's possibile it is a matter of privileges? Or maybe I have to install some special features?
Under the machine i try to, I'm not administrator.

thanks

Comment: Please post the actual error

Comment: `Format-Hex` requires PowerShell version 5.0 or higher. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I've got version 2.0, so it could be the issue. thnx. Anyway the error is + format-hex <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (format-h
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: As the error says your PowerShell does not know the command. If you are using PowerShell Version 2.0 then the `Format-Help` Cmdlet is not available (as @Jelphy said). See [Windows PowerShell 2.0 - Overview of Cmdlets Available in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714569.aspx) for more Information.

Comment: It's version issue. Your version will be less than 5. You can check it from the following answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/1690709