# Slight modification to powershell command

Tags: powershell, copy, zip

This powershell command works perfectly to copy and extract a zip file across two directories:

```
$shell = New-Object -COM Shell.Application
$target = $shell.NameSpace('D:\destination\')
$zip = $shell.NameSpace('D:\source\version_*.zip')
$target.CopyHere($zip.Items(), 16)
```

However I am struggling with a modification to make it select only the *latest* zip file from the source.

Comment: What defines "latest"? Is that the modified date on the file, ferinstance?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The newest zip file in the directory, so mod date would be perfect, or creation date of course.

Comment: Which version of powershell are you on?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to determine that! I am googling how to find out :)

Comment: In the `Related` sidebar, it should be the first tagged question.

Comment: Link added inline as what's top of the "Related" section is subject to change: [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the zip file with the most recent modification date in a given directory:

```
$source = "C:\temp"
$destination = "C:\temp\output"

$zipFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter "*.zip" |
               Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
               Select-Object -First 1

Expand-Archive -Path $zipFile.FullName -DestinationPath $destination
```

This works by searching for all zip files, sorting them by the modified date descending and then grabbing the "first" one (according to the defined sort order).

I've also used the `Expand-Archive` command to extract the zip to a specified destination. If you need to copy the zip then that's easy enough using the `Copy-Item` cmdlet first.

---

As some commenters have pointed out: `Expand-Archive` was introduced in version 5 of PowerShell.

However the logic of getting the "latest" file is unchanged and can easily be plumbed in to your existing script:

```
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($zipFile.FullName)
```

Comment: `Expand-Archive` was not introduced until v5.

Comment: `Expand-Archive` #requires -Version 5.0 and `-recurse` wasn't in OPs. question.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my requirements thanks very much. I had not specified that I wanted to overwrite the destination, my bad, so I added a `-Force` flag on the Expand. Thanks again.

Comment: Also updated answer to handle earlier versions of PowerShell `;-)`