# New Azure PowerShell Module - command for finding latest version not displaying any output

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

According to the Prerequisites section of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell) official Azure documentation you can find the latest version of the [new Azure Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.2.0) by running `Get-Module -ListAvailable Az` command. I successfully installed the new module on my `Windows 10 Pro - Update 1809`. But when I run the above command, I get no output as shown in the image below. **Question**: What I may be missing here, or is it a bug?

**NOTE**: The question is specific to the above command for the new `Azure Az module` and NOT like the one already nicely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/1232087).

[image]

Comment: same behaviour here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same behavior as you. The [Get-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module?view=powershell-6#description) cmdlet gets the PowerShell modules that have been imported, or that can be imported, into a PowerShell session. On my side, there is not the name `Az` module just `Az.*` modules in the output of `Get-Module -ListAvailable`. So I get no output by running `Get-Module -ListAvailable Az` command.

[image]

Generally, you could get the PowerShell modules name `Az` installed on a computer directly by using [Get-InstalledModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/get-installedmodule?view=powershell-6).
[image]

Comment: The question is specific to the article claiming that "Get-Module -ListAvailable Az" command will display the version of PowerShell installed on our machine. But I do want to thank you for taking your time to verify my observation and then providing a way to find out the latest version installed on the machine.