# Flutter showing issue while installation

Tags: flutter

```
C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor
'git rev-parse HEAD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
'dir /a:l "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\" 2>nul   | find ">     bin [" 2>nul' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590], locale en-IN)
-CreateProcessW failed 2
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 4f22c8be3f4f8ba9)
\CreateProcessW failed 2                                                                                               Crash report written to C:\src\flutter\flutter_05.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

I have installed git also, but still the flutter in stopped unexpectedly

Comment: Looks like you do not have git installed or not added to `PATH`. Please try `git --version` in a command line window and post the output.

Comment: C:\src\flutter>git --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1

Comment: Ensure you have the `%SystemRoot%\system32` directory in your `Path` https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: Please also check the installed PowerShell version if you use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version

Comment: Yes, %SystemRoot%\system32 directory exists and the scenario was that first time I installed flutter with android studio it worked perfectly but as I uninstalled it and tried to install with dart and visual studio it throws above error

Comment: What does "and tried to install with dart" mean exactly? You could try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: I fired the power shell command the result is bellow: C:\>powershell -Command "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion"

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  590

Comment: Powershell should be fine. Please check if your installation is ok by executing the commands in the link I posted before.

Comment: If it still does not work, check if the path to the Android SDK contains a space. Also try `flutter channel dev`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused that the flutter for web development doesn't need android. But I found that still flutter is not used for web development..