# PowerShell How to Combine CSV Files Error Same Headers

Tags: powershell, csv

I have multiple reports for people in DLs I am producing where I use the below logic to combine newly added people to existing people in the DL in a CSV.

It works when there is more than 1 new user record in the newly added file, but if there's only 1 record, I get the below error and I'm not sure why?

```
$csv = import-csv "C:\somefile.csv"
$csv1 = import-csv "C:\somefile1.csv"

$both = $csv + $csv1 | export-csv "C:\newfile.csv"
```

which results in this error

```
 Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
 At line:1 char:1
 + $Both = $csv + $csv1
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Appreciate some insights. Thanks

Comment: What Powershell version are you using? (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version)

Comment: I'm on PSVersion  5.1.14409.1018

Comment: `Import-Csv "C:\somefile1.csv" | Export-Csv "C:\somefile.csv" -Append -NoType`

Comment: Not sure I understand Ansgar? I need 2 csv files merged into 1. Your solution doesn't add one to the other...

Comment: Somehow the types are different? One is an object while the other is an array. How do I set the variable to an array no matter what? Looks like PS is treating the csv with the 1 record in it, like an object and I don't want that.

Comment: [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) doesn't return anything. You can't assign it to a variable `$Both` (at least it is useless.)

Comment: It works if I hard code the variable [array]$csv. PowerShell appears to treat a csv file with only 1 record in it as an object. That's why it was failing...

Comment: the `Import-CSV` cmdlet will import multiple files if they have the same header. take a look at `Get-Help Import-Csv -Parameter Path` and you will see `-Path <String[]>`. that means you can give it multiple file names ... [*grin*]

Comment: The code snippet I posted appends the data rows of the second file to the first one, assuming that both files have the same columns.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to waste everyone's time. I found the answer myself... It works if I hard code the 
variable [array]$csv. PowerShell appears to treat a csv file with only 1 record in it as an object. The types were off. So, that's why it was failing...

Comment: Good catch. Also thanks for posting a solution with explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky, a parameter can be an array.

```
import-csv file1.csv,file2.csv | export-csv file3.csv
```