# WARNING: Multiple variants of AWS Tools for PowerShell are currently installed

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

When I run a powershell script, I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Multiple variants of AWS Tools for PowerShell (AWSPowerShell,
> AWSPowerShell.NetCore or AWS.Tools) are currently installed. Please
> run 'Get-Module -Name
> AWSPowerShell,AWSPowerShell.NetCore,AWS.Tools.Common -ListAvailable'
> for details. To avoid problems with cmdlet auto-importing, it is
> suggested to only install one variant. AWS.Tools is the new
> modularized version of AWS Tools for PowerShell, compatible with
> PowerShell Core 6+ and Windows Powershell 5.1+ (when .NET Framework
> 4.7.2+ is installed). AWSPowerShell.NetCore is the monolithic variant that supports all AWS services in a single large module, it is
> compatible with PowerShell Core 6+ and Windows Powershell 3+ (when
> .NET Framework 4.7.2+ is installed). AWSPowerShell is the legacy
> module for older systems which are either running Windows PowerShell 2
> or cannot be updated to .NET Framework 4.7.2 (or newer).

Screenshot:

[image]

How do I fix the warning? Do I uninstall one or 2 of these modules? Which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going purely by the error message:

> How do I fix the warning?

You ensure that only *one* of the three listed module (groups) is installed:

- Modern, modular *group* of related modules:

  - `AWS.Tools.*`, core module is [`AWS.Tools.Common`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.Common), installation-helper module is [`AWS.Tools.Installer`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.Installer)
- Legacy modules (monolithic):

  - [`AWSPowerShell`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSPowerShell)
  - [`AWSPowerShell.NetCore`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSPowerShell.NetCore)

> Do I uninstall one or 2 of these modules? Which ones?

Yes. Which ones to uninstall and thereby implicitly which one to *keep* depends on your needs and [which powershell version you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version):

- (a) If you're running Windows PowerShell 5.1 and have .NET Framework 4.7.2+ installed, or you're running [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), keep the `AWS.Tools.*` modules.
- (b) If you're still running Windows PowerShell 3 or 4, and have .NET Framework 4.7.2+ or higher installed, keep the `AWSPowerShell.NetCore` module.
- (c) If you're still running Windows PowerShell 2 or a higher version, but cannot install .NET Framework 4.7.2+, keep the legacy `AWSPowerShell` module.

For instance, to go with (a):

Note

- To be safe, *run with elevation* (as admin), so that removal of modules that were installed in the `AllUser` scope can be removed.
- Any non-installed modules among the specified ones are quietly ignored.
- Start a new PowerShell session afterwards (modules already imported in the current session remain in memory, even after uninstallation; however, you can also remove them individually from memory with `Remove-Module`).

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable AWSPowerShell, AWSPowerShell.NetCore |
  Uninstall-Module -Force
```