Powershell SimplySQL and MySQL, how to connect?
Downloaded MySQL 8.0 [latest] as it still had Workbench. Set it up and Workbench works perfect with DB user uid in addition to root user. Trying to then use PS SimplySQL module:
Import-Module -Name SimplySql
$port = 3306  
$server = "127.0.0.1"
#$server = "localhost"  #also fails if used
$connName = "MySQL"  #valid, tested connection name
$uid = "root"
$pw = "8R?suppr1943" 
$db = "sakila"
$pw1 = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pw -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = [pscredential]::new($uid, $pw1)

$sqlConnect = Open-MySqlConnection -ConnectionName $connName -Server $server -port $port -Credential $creds -Database $db

Get error 'cannot connect to server'.  


Can you enable general log ? And share the output  that is added after running te powershell script ?

The version of powershell that you use would be nice too. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version )

Why ODBC ??? The module seems to connect without ODBC too (using the default protocol, whichever that is, the MySQL client uses.

I was using PS 5.1. I uninstalled all MySQL components and cleaned registry. Then re-installed ver. 8.0.39 with Workbench. The SimplySQL code I posted still failed immediately with 'cannot connect to server'. However, I also tried 64bit ODBC drivers and this worked
$user = "admin"
$pw = "password"
$db = 'sakila'
$connstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 9.0 ANSI
 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=$db;User=$user;Password=$pw;Option=3;"
$query = "SELECT * FROM sakila.actor;"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring
$conn.open()
$cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
$ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
(New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) | out-null
$conn.close()
$ds.Tables[0] | Out-GridView -Title "Actors" -PassThru

Tried several sets of parameters with SimplySQL with same immediate error. I was testing mySQL for another user and we decided his project was better served with SQLite rather than MySQL. This thread can be closed and I appreciate earlier comments.

these comment should be added to the question (because they seem to add value to the question).  They should not be putted in an answer, because it's no answer....
